# do postback from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a aspx page and I am creating a link as

```
<a href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('Download', 1);" > DownFileName.pdf </a>
```

and my code behind is

```
string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; // parameter
string eventName = Request["__EVENTTARGET"]; // Event name

if(eventName!=null && eventName.Trim().Length > 0 && parameter != null && parameter.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                if(eventName.EqualsTo("Download"))
                {
                    int fileId;
                    int.TryParse(parameter, out fileId);
                    DownloadAttachment(fileId);
                }
            }
```

The file was successfully downloaded.
but When I click a save button, again the file is downloading and the save button click event is not firing.

One more thing, The save button click event is triggering when I click save button button before clicking the link button to download.

Whenever postback occurs it `Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]` and  `Request["__EVENTTARGET"];`  values are retains.

Comment: What save button are you talking about?  All I see is the link.